# Why my tomato plant branches become dry?

Tags: tomatoes

Hi everyone I ave very strange phenomena going on my tomato plants branches bend and then dry also top of plant also get dry. Not sure what is the cause of it we have 35 Celsius Temprature but I have setup shade on plants to protect them from too much sun light but still branches bend and dry out. I have captured picture of my plants please help how to solve the problem it’s my 3rd year of my garden and every year I get into some problem. First year I had problem with tall tomatoes they would break in pots and had germination issue. 2nd year I had massive mealy bugs attack and this year I have problem if this dry leaves stems.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Update : peppers and some tomato healthy plants

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You are overwate4ring them too much. On one we see a lake in the pot, on the others we see mud. I think also soil you use is not good. You should write much more on how you care your plants (e.g. soil origin, how much and often you water, fertilizers, ...), so that we can tell you what to improve.

Comment: @user889030 Agreed, we need more information. For instance: Do these pots have drainage holes? What kind of dirt are you using? Why are you shading these tomato's? Are you using fertilizer? What zone do you live in? http://www.plantsdb.gr/en/general-cultivation/hardiness-zones/274-hardiness-zones-map

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi no am not over watering them , i give them once a day or after two days . here temperature is high if i not give them water let say for 3 days then they will die totally as pots dry totally. soil i got from one dried cannal here in Asia we do not have a lot of resources so we cant use compost and packed soils from shops. using iron tools i soften the soil of pots once a month

Comment: @Rob ya the pots have drainage holes below  , i have taken soil from dried Canal and have filled pots with it. . ya am shading tomato because here temperature is high   now we have 37 Celsius temperature although summer is just started here , as after month temp will reach to 50  Celsius. ... continue

Comment: @rob  no i not used fertilizers of shops , but i make my own natural composts like i collect egg shells and i add egg shells to pots when i fill pot because i have found in youtube that eggs shells are good for tomato other than that i store dead dried plants of my garden which later decompose and i also mix them with pots soil.  Am in zone 10 ( USDA: 10  / AHS: 12 ) pakistan peshawar city.

Comment: There is too much water in the pot. Roots of tomatoes do no like it. Try to get some sand, so that soil could store more water, without suffocating roots. [Note for readers: this sand trick works only on such very compact soil, on light soil it does the contrary effect]

Comment: @user889030 Do you grow all your plants in that soil? Are you growing any other vegetables in the same type of soil? If so, are those plants doing fine?

Comment: @Rob ya i grow all plants in same soil , i have added more pics of healthy plants , peppers plants are 100% ok , some tomato plants are also ok you can see i add their picture but their some of leaves start bending am not sure why the bend occur after that bend these branches will dry you can see plants are healthy and after few days they will dry again .

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi hmmm if i not give them water a day they will dry up due to high temperature ,  ok so you saying i should mix sand with this soil , ok right i will try this thanks for tip :) on weekend i will try to get sand and then will experiment with it

Comment: @user889030 Either way, get some support for those tomato stalks. Tie them up to a stick or trellis of some sort so they dont have to try so hard to keep themselves upright.

Comment: @Rob ya right i will add sticks to each tomato plant , thanks

Comment: @Rob i did some search on it , do you think its septoria leaf sport disease or not : https://youtu.be/OOw06jo6If0  
https://www.walterreeves.com/gardening-q-and-a/tomato-septoria-leaf-spot/